# Plain text to C array test vectors

Tags: c, bash, parsing

I am implementing AES as described by [FIPS_197](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf) and I wish to implement the test cases described in Appendix C (C1 - C3). I have copied the test cases into a text file `FIPS_197_tests.txt` That looks like this:

> # Test cases from FIPS_192 Appendix C
>   # Plaintext
>   # Key
>   # Output
>   #
>   # C.1    AES-128 (Nk=4, Nr=10)
>   00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
>   000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
>   69c4e0d86a7b0430d8cdb78070b4c55a
>   # C.2    AES-192 (Nk=6, Nr=12)
>   00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
>   000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f1011121314151617
>   dda97ca4864cdfe06eaf70a0ec0d7191
>   # C.3    AES-256 (Nk=8, Nr=14)
>   00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
>   000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f
>   8ea2b7ca516745bfeafc49904b496089

I would like to create a header file `FIPS_197_tests.h` that defines some test vectors that would be easily usable in C. For example the first test vector:

```
// C.1  AES-128 (Nk=4, Nr=10)
unsigned char Key_1[4][4] = {
        {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33},
        {0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77},
        {0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb},
        {0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff} };
unsigned char PlainText_1[4][4]  = {
        {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03},
        {0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07},
        {0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b},
        {0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f} };
unsigned char CipherText_1[4][4]  = {
        {0x69, 0xc4, 0xe0, 0xd8},
        {0x6a, 0x7b, 0x04, 0x30},
        {0xd8, 0xcd, 0xb7, 0x80},
        {0x70, 0xb4, 0xc5, 0x5a} };
```

There are only 3 sets of test vectors and I could just do it by hand, but I have found myself making hex test vectors in C often and would like to have a more clever solution than hand typing hex arrays.

## Key issues to be addressed:

1. **Naming**: Vectors come in sets of Three

   - The first is a *Key_n* array
   - The second is a *PlainText_n* array
   - The third is the *CipherText_n* array
2. **Sizing**: The values in the vectors are all in hex but do not always populate arrays of size *[4][4]* arrays should be sized correctly

So far I have this script that makes things a bit easier, but nothing that does the whole job:

```sh
cat FIPS_192_tests.txt | sed '/^#/ d; s/../0x&, /g' | xargs -n4 | rev | sed 's/,//' | rev | sed 's|^|{|; s|$|},|'
```

## In summary

I am hoping for a way to easily create hex test vectors in C from a text file containing long text strings. The test vectors come in sets of 3 per test case and should be named accordingly ( A_1, B_1, C_1, A_2, B_2 ... etc. ). The test vectors are of varrying size so some arrays should be declared as `type [4][4]` while others should be declared `type [4][5]`

## An ideal solution would allow for the following elements of a text file to be variable:

1. The number of consecutive lines that defined a test case.
2. The *Base Names* for each line (Key_n, Ciphertext_n, Apple_n, Banana_n).
3. The data type for each *Base Name*.
4. The size of each array.
5. The format of the data being read in (hex, decimal, binary, ...)

It might be called like:
`./solution -i FIPS_197_tests.txt -n 3 -b "Key, PlainText, CipherText" -d "unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char" -f HEX -o FIPS_197_tests.h`

Comment: once the file of vectors is generated. (be sure they are in a valid format for C code)  Then just include the file into your program, compile and run.

Comment: If the file of vectors is continually changing, then just read it into your program, making use of `malloc()` (or what ever) to allocate the needed space

Comment: Suggest, before each set of vectors, insert a line that contains the row/column count for the next set of vectors

Comment: I would not be opposed to some form of formatting for the input text file. The point of this question though is that I frequently find myself manually translating long un-formatted text files into test vectors. If there existed a solution to this that required minimal formatting it would still be useful. The goal here is to decrease repetitive and tedious work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as complete a solution as the nice program provided by @TheRockSays, but this is more limited in line with your `cat`, `sed`, `xargs`, `rev`, `sed`, ... approach, though replacing all the utilities with a single call to `awk`, e.g.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        a[1]="unsigned char Key_1[4][4] = "
        a[2]="unsigned char PlainText_1[4][4]  = "
        a[3]="unsigned char CipherText_1[4][4]  = "
    }
    /^#/ { if(n) exit; next }
    {
        for (i=1; i<length($1); i+=2)
            if ((i % 8) == 1) {
                if (i == 1)
                    printf "\n%s{\n%8s{0x%s", a[++n], " ", substr($1,i,2)
                else
                    printf "},\n%8s{0x%s", " ", substr($1,i,2)
            }
            else
                printf ", 0x%s", substr($1,i,2)
        print "}};"
    }
' FIPS_197_tests.txt
```

(to test, you can simply *select-copy* and *middle-mouse-paste* the above into an xterm with the present working directory containng `FIPS_197_tests.txt`)

Granted, in the wish-list of things, you would have to manually provide the array names and you would have to change the `printf` format string for decimal, hex, etc..., but for a quick shell solution to the initial parse of the `FIPS_197_tests.txt` file -- it sure beats entering all the arrays by hand.

**Example Output**

```
unsigned char Key_1[4][4] = {
        {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33},
        {0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77},
        {0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb},
        {0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff}};

unsigned char PlainText_1[4][4]  = {
        {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03},
        {0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07},
        {0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b},
        {0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f}};

unsigned char CipherText_1[4][4]  = {
        {0x69, 0xc4, 0xe0, 0xd8},
        {0x6a, 0x7b, 0x04, 0x30},
        {0xd8, 0xcd, 0xb7, 0x80},
        {0x70, 0xb4, 0xc5, 0x5a}};
```

Comment: This script works well to reproduce the output I described, could you explain in your solution how I might edit this script to add a a[4]=key_2, a[5]=PlainText_2 ... change the array size to be larger than [4][4] potentially [4][5] or [5][5]?

Comment: The `awk` script has 3-rules. The `BEGIN` rule where you just name your arrays as the elements of the `a[]` array. The next rule, `/^#/ { if(n) exit; next }` just checks if the first char is a `'#'` and then checks if the variable `n` is set, if so, exits, otherwise, it just skips to the next input record (line). The last rule is where you iterate over each of the first set of lines between comments. You loop over the first field (the whole line of numbers) by 2's. The `i%8` controls the columns `8/2 = 4` 2-char columns. So you would adjust that to add columns, e.g. `10/2 = 5-col`.

Comment: For instance if you were going to read the AES `192` or `256`, set of lines, the only array that would change would be `PlainText_1`. You would just have to add a counter or flag and check if `line == 2` of the set, then use a different value for the modulo operation. You can use another array, say `b[]` where you set `b[1] = 8`, `b[2] = 10` and `b[3] = 8` in `BEGIN` and use `i % b[counter] == 1` as the test (it would take a few other changes, but that would be the basic approach)

Comment: Also note, `awk` provides the `length(string)` function to get the length of the string. You could check that before looping over the characters so you would know how many 2-char values you would need to read. As with any tool, you need to tell it what to do, but `awk` provides a full set of tools to allow you to do whatever you need (remember, it just process each line in the file applying the rules you write, the BEGIN rule happens before the 1st line is read, and the `END` rule happens after the last. [awk guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: I like this approach to the solution, I have taken your answer and am trying to augment it to create the tool I need. I started flipping though that awk guide after reading your initial post. ```awk``` seems like it may do the job quite well here

Comment: It takes a while to make friends with `awk`, but once I had I was glad I did.. I used `sed` long before `awk` and never took the plunge. I'm glad I finally did. What is nice about awk (and confusing) is that it processes one line at a time, and you can wirite as many rules as you need to transform that line. Under the hood you have all the normal programming tools, arrays, loops, floating-point math, and many string functions to work with. Commit to doing 5 basic examples with `awk`, and when  you are done -- you will likely have your new -- go to --  Swiss Army Knife for all your text needs.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Now it works. The following code has the following assumptions:

- You have 3 lines per test case, each for the `Key_1`, `PlainText_1` and `CipherText_1` respectively.
- Each of the `Key_1`, `PlainText_1` and `CipherText_1` have exactly 32 bits and stored in [4][4] matrixes.

Have a look at this code. Try putting a file and see the output. You should see With each test case the updated values of `Key_1`, `PlainText_1` and `CipherText_1`.

```cpp
using namespace std;

void readFile(std::string fileName) {
    unsigned char Key_1[4][4];
    unsigned char PlainText_1[4][4];
    unsigned char CipherText_1[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            Key_1[i][j] = 0x00 ; PlainText_1[i][j] = 0x00 ; CipherText_1[i][j] = 0x00;
        }
    }

    std::ifstream reader;
    reader.open(fileName);

    bool commentBlock = true;
    int line_flag = 0;
    int str2int = 0;
    int line_idx = 0;

    if (reader.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(reader, line)) {
            if (line.substr(0, 1) != "#")
                commentBlock = false;
            else{
                printf("\n");
                printf("Key_1 Contents:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        printf("%x\t",Key_1[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                printf("\n");

                printf("PlainText_1 Contents:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        printf("%x\t",PlainText_1[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                printf("\n");

                printf("CipherText_1 Contents:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        printf("%x\t",CipherText_1[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                printf("\n");

                commentBlock = true;
                while (commentBlock) {
                    getline(reader, line);
                    if (line.substr(0, 1) != "#")
                        commentBlock = false;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Read line:" << std::endl;
            printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
            line_idx = 0;
            if (line_flag > 2){
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        Key_1[i][j] = 0x00 ; PlainText_1[i][j] = 0x00 ; CipherText_1[i][j] = 0x00;
                    }
                }
                line_flag = 0;
            }

            switch (line_flag){
            case 0:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            Key_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                    }
                }
                line_flag++;
                break;
            case 1:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            PlainText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                    }
                }
                line_flag++;
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int * 16;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                        switch(line.at(line_idx)){
                        case 'a':
                            str2int = 10;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            str2int = 11;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'c':
                            str2int = 12;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            str2int = 13;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            str2int = 14;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            str2int = 15;
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        default:
                            str2int = stoi(line.substr(line_idx, 1));
                            CipherText_1[i][j] += str2int;
                            break;
                        }
                        line_idx ++;
                    }
                }
                line_flag++;
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Key_1 Contents:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                printf("%x\t",Key_1[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("PlainText_1 Contents:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                printf("%x\t",PlainText_1[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("CipherText_1 Contents:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                printf("%x\t",CipherText_1[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    else {
        cerr << "Can't open file " + fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very complete solution. And completely solves the example I posted. It's terrific, however I was hoping that there might be a solution that allowed the following elements of the problem I described to be variable:  1. The number of consecutive lines that defined a test case. 2. The _Base Names_ for each line (Key_n, Ciphertext_n, Apple_n, Banana_n). 3. The data type for each _Base Name_. 4. The size of each array. 5. The format of the data being read in (hex, decimal, binary, ...) .

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but when I use the code to read the file `FIPS_197_tests.txt`, for the first row of `Key_1 Contents:`, I get `"d4      45      7f      e8"`, with similar value for the remaining 3 rows, and then each `PlainText_1` and `CipherText_1` the rows are all zeros. [Example Source Used](https://paste.opensuse.org/20460599)

Comment: You are right @David C.Rankin . There was a logical error causing `PlainText_1 ` and `CipherText_1 ` to be all zeros. I fixed it now but the values printing are not correct I will try to fix it.

Comment: @Lenna To make it that generic in C++ requires a lot of work. I don't know `awk` but @David C. Rankin solution seems a lot smoother.

Comment: Yep, just confirmed - works like a champ now. And you are right, it does take a lot to write in C++. You can also take a similar approach with reading with `getline` and looping with `substr` picking out two chars at a time and using `std::stoi` with `base=16` (see [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) which may simplify things a bit. But well worth the upvote for effort and persistence.